# Multi-Level Dropdown List

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm writing an Angular 2 application and I need to have a "weird" dropdownlist element that, on a given option, should show a calendar, something like what I'm attaching bellow:

[image]

It might also be important to mention that I'm using PrimeNG (from Primefaces) in my application. They have dropdownlists and calendars available as components, but will I ever be able to tell that a given dropdownlist option should expand into a calendar?

Thanks for any help or input you can give on this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about PrimeNG, but yes, it can definitely be done one way or another.

There are 'onChange' events on the PrimeNG dropdown component. In the event handlers for those, you can check for a 'custom' value and trigger the display of the calendar component (have one already in the template but conditionally attach it to the DOM with `*ngIf`). The PrimeNG calendar component has onSelect events that you can then listen for.

You could manually attach listeners with Renderer for those calendar events in the callback for the dropdown list events or you can use regular `(event)` binding in the template. In the latter case, you don't have to worry about stray events because the calendar would only ever be attached to the view when you wanted it to be.